# Macros to access identifiers with similar names

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Imagine you have many identifiers such as UARTxREG (where x is a number).

Is there a way to write a macro such as:

```
#define CHANNEL_ONE 1
#define UART_REG(channel)
/* Later */
UART_REG(CHANNEL_ONE) = 1;
```

So that this will expand to:

```
UART1REG
```

I can do this is a pass the literal numbers (1,2,3 etc..) into the macro but when I try to pass in a macro I get into the problem of the macro not expanding correctly.

I currently have:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define UART_REG(channel)            STRINGIFY(UART##channel##REG)
/* Later */
UART_REG(UART_ONE) = regVal;
```

However this is not expanding `channel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to stringify:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHANNEL_ONE 1
#define UARTREG_(channel) UART##channel##REG
#define UART_REG(channel) UARTREG_(channel)

int main(void)
{
    char UART1REG = 'a';
    char UART2REG = 'b';
    char UART3REG = 'c';

    UART_REG(CHANNEL_ONE) = 'd';

    printf("%c\n", UART_REG(CHANNEL_ONE));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both answer work but this one removes that extra step. I was hoping to do it all in one but this will work.

Comment: Yeah. That's what was giving me trouble. On the plus side I can abstract the actual "doing" of the Macro and so for different HW I can do it differently :-)

Comment: FWIW, this is called *token pasting*.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to wrap your concatenation to another macro:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define UART_REG2(channel)           STRINGIFY(UART##channel##REG)
#define UART_REG(channel)            UART_REG2(channel)
```

Note that `STRINGIFY`-macro makes your result `"UART1REG"` which may not be what you want.